# MySQL: Fetch cursor into DATE

Tags: mysql, date, stored-procedures, cursor

I Defined the following procedure which compiles correctly.

http://pastebin.com/pBHFctHq

When i call that procedure it returns an error:

`ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect date value: ''2012-12-30'' for column 'date_part' at row 11`

I think the problem is fetching the date from the cursor, how would i solve it??

*small description of the code: i am looping through different tables , and gathering information on each partition that may exist in the table (each table is range partitioned by date)*

Comment: i copied the procedure to pastebin, please undo the downvote

Comment: is your PARTITION_DESCRIPTION column for INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS table is date type?

Comment: @sourcecode: you are right, it is longtext which represent a date, i need to convert it to DATE, so that the cursor will loop over dates, `replace(longtext,"'","")` works, is their a better way?

Comment: i posted 1 ans ...try it then tell me is it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are comparing string with date that's why you are getting error..
you can use this for comparision:

```
           TO_DATE(PARTITION_DESCRIPTION,'YYYY-MM-DD')      // in oracle this will work

           STR_TO_DATE(PARTITION_DESCRIPTION, '%Y-%m-%d')   // in mysql this will work

           convert(varchar(20),PARTITION_DESCRIPTION,104)   // in ms-sql this will work
```

so your code look like this:

```
   BLOCK2: BEGIN
                            DECLARE loop1_eof INT DEFAULT FALSE;

                            DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT TO_DATE(PARTITION_DESCRIPTION,'YYYY-MM-DD')
                            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS
                            WHERE TABLE_NAME=tmp_title AND TABLE_SCHEMA='test1';    
                            DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET loop1_eof = TRUE;

                            OPEN cur1;
                            loop1: LOOP
                                    FETCH cur1 INTO date_part;
                                    SELECT max(id) from `test1`.tmp_title where CurrentDate < date_part;
                                    IF loop1_eof THEN
                                            CLOSE cur1;
                                            LEAVE loop1;
                                    END IF;
                            END LOOP loop1;
                    END BLOCK2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have quotes around the date value: `''2012-12-30''`. The single-quotes inside the outside ones should be removed. That's not a valid `DATE` field value.

Comment: This filed is returned from the information schema, how i may remove the single quotes automatically?